# Laravel Response::json gives cross domain error i browser even if header is Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Tags: ajax, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, same-origin-policy

I got this Laravel 4 problem that is really confusing to me. I Created these two methods on the same controller. The controller in declared to be restful. The ajax request is from a different domain.

Does not work

```
public function getOwnlist(){
    $test = User::with(array("images", "images.category"))->find(Auth::user()->id);
    return Response::json($test, 200, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'));
}
```

Works

```
public function getLatest(){
        $images = DB::table("images")->where("public","=","1")->orderBy("created_at")->take(10)->get();
        return Response::json($images, 200, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'));
}
```

The browser get a the standard cross domain error.

Answer (score 3):

This example works for me you may try this.

```
public function getOwnlist(){
   $images = User::with('images.category')->find(Auth::getUser()->getAttribute('id'));
   return Response::json($images, 200, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'));
}
```

Also, I highly recommend setting those on the constructor of your Controller Base instead of setting the headers in each response. Or you can create one only to serve API and extend from it.

Should be something like:

```
protected $response; // This is a global variable on you BaseController

// This goes on your BaseController constructor 
$this->response = Response::make();
$this->response->headers->add(array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

I found some issues with Cross Domain AJAX while using jQuery, it only works for me if I specify the domain instead of using `*`.

More information on Eloquent Models:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have changed to JSONP instead which solves the cross domain issues. Setting the headers in the each method was just for testing/illustration. I have one more question though. Whu so you use Auth::getUser()->getAttribute('id') instead of Auth::user()->id is there any special reason?

Comment: Isn't a big different depends on your configuration, for instance if you have your id field protected like protected $guarded = array('id') you wouldn't be able to do Auth::getUser()->id because you protect this property but if you use getAttribute('id') works because you bypass this protection with this function. It's just a formalism i guess :), I hope this helps.

Comment: Angel Ramirez, very useful your answer, ..thank you so much. After searching several hours I solved my problem.

Comment: @GeraldoNovais I'm glad it helped my pleasure.