# how to redirect on third party url in laravel form controller

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, paypal

I want to use Paypal in my project which is developed with angularjs for front-end and Laravel for back-end so my question is how can I redirect in Paypal ??

I want to redirect on Paypal form Laravel controller

I am trying with

```
return Redirect::to('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=  
AP-5HP41952DG658420R');
```

but it's not working it giving me **302 found error** !!!

can anyone help me out !!!!

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
return redirect('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Source https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Redirect::away` to make an off-site redirect

```
return Redirect::away('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-5HP41952DG658420R');
```

Comment: It is totally working for me (actually with `away()` and `to()` as well) I'd need to see more code. Controller function and route at least. Also 302 is not an error, it's the status code for a redirect. Where exactly are you seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it should be in comment . Basically `return Redirect::to('http://google.com')` will work even for off-site redirect . Make sure you have included **return** keyword. 
Another way is to allow cross domain origin by adding in header.
[enable cross origin access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764309/laravel-responsejson-gives-cross-domain-error-i-browser-even-if-header-is-acce)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding , This worked for me

```
protected $except = [
    //
    '*'
];
```

In VerifyCsrfToken middleware. This will allow you to access third party url's